# Azure Table Storage filter gt with full stop/period not working

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-table-storage

I have a RowKey in Azure table store that is sperated with a full stop/period, however when I use it to end of the section in the and then filter ge the full stop/ period gets ingnored.

eg

"x.xyz.123",
"x.xyzq.123"

PartitionKey eq 'someptk' and RowKey ge 'x.xyz.'

this returns both records and I only want the first one.

I am using the c# sdk

Any suggestions would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `RowKey ge 'x.xyz.'`

The period doesn't get ignored, you're asking (in human readable text) "Give me all the elements where the RowKey is greater than or equal to 'x.xyz.'.

The result you're getting is correct, since `(int)'.' == 46` and `(int)'q' == 113`. So `"x.xyzq." > "x.xyz."` equals to true.

You might want to look at using both `ge` and `le` to set both upper and lower boundaries. For more information, please refer to [Querying tables and entities - Supported Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#supported-comparison-operators).

Comment: that makes sense but looks like my thinking isn't going to work, becuase if I add RowKey lt 'x.xyz.' that disregards all records which have more characters after which they do.

Comment: i think  RowKey lt 'x.xyz/' is working